# Can short-term hunger influence anger?

Tags: cognitive-psychology, physiology, feeding

We know that hunger, whether short-lived or prolonged, causes physiological changes in our bodies. These may have psychological effects too as brain functions are slowed down and can have an impact on psychological processes. In fact, long-term memory formation can be enhanced by mild food-deprivation (Hirano et al, 2013). If hunger influences brain function, then it may have an effect on our emotional states.

**Questions**

1. Therefore, if one is hungry (mild food deprivation), is one more likely to exhibit anger generally more so than if one did not experience the hunger?
2. Are there any studies demonstrating angry responses positive influenced by hunger in people compared to responses by people who were not hungry?

**References**

- Hirano, Y., Masuda, T., Naganos, S., Matsuno, M., Ueno, K., Miyashita, J.H. & Saitoe, M. (2013). Fasting launches CRTC to facilitate long-term memory formation in drosophila. *Science*, 339(6118), 443-446

Answer (score -1):

yes, hunger increase philogeneticaly older brain activity and supress prefrontal cortex...
so it could be anger or some other negative affect.

http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0149763402000076

http://www.jneurosci.org/content/21/14/5304.short

http://psycnet.apa.org/journals/bul/126/6/890/